# Limit of Convergent Sequence

Tags: real-analysis

**Given** 
$z_1 = 1\;\;$ 
For $\;\;n \,\in \,\mathbb{Z^+}, \;z_{(n+1)} = \sqrt{1 + z_n}.$

**To Do** 
Prove that $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$ is convergent and find its limit.

**My Work**
Let $\;t \;=\; \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$ 
$\forall \;x \,\in \,\mathbb{R}, \;$ let $\;f(x) = (1 + x) - x^2.$ 
Then $\;f^{\prime}(x) = (1 - 2x) \;\Rightarrow\; $
$\forall \;x \,\in \,[1, t), \;f^{\prime}(x) < 0.$ 
Further, $\;f(1) = 1\;$ and $\;f(t) = 0.$

Therefore, $\;\forall \;x \,\in \,[1, t), \;f(x) > 0 \;\Rightarrow $ 
$(1 + x) > x^2 \;\Rightarrow\; \sqrt{1 + x} > x.$ 
Therefore, $\;\forall \;z_n \,\in \,[1, t), \;z_{(n+1)} > z_n.$

Also, $\;x \,\in \,[1, t) \;\Rightarrow\; (1 + x) < (1 + t) = t^2.$ 
Therefore, $\;x \,\in \,[1, t) \;\Rightarrow\; \sqrt{1 + x} < t.$ 
Therefore, $\;z_n \,\in \,[1, t) \;\Rightarrow\; z_{(n+1)} < t.$

Consequently, $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$ is a strictly increasing sequence 
that is bounded above by $\;t \;=\; \dfrac{1 + \sqrt{5}}{2}.$ 
Therefore, $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$ is convergent.

**However** 
In order to find the limit of $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$, I must find its
**least upper bound.**
I know that $\;t\;$ is an upper bound for $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$. 
I know that $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$ is strictly increasing in the interval $\;[1, t).$

I **suspect** that $\;t\;$ is the **least upper bound.** 
**But,** I am unable to **prove** that $\;\langle z_n\rangle\;$ does not have 
some **other upper bound** that is **slight less than** $\;t.\;$

**Request Help** proving the last link.

**Addendum**
It was suggested that the following link is on point:
[$a, z_1 \gt 0$ and $z_{n + 1} = (a + z_n)^{\frac 1 2}$ then $(z_n)$ is monotone and bounded?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715018/a-z-1-gt-0-and-z-n-1-a-z-n-frac-1-2-then-z-n-is-monotone)

If I'm not mistaken, that link focuses on demonstrating that the sequence is bounded and convergent, which is not the issue in my query.

Answer (score 0):

I worked on this for several hours, and then a few minutes after I posted the query, I thought of a proof.  I was about to delete the query, but somebody had already responded with a comment.  Therefore, I'll simply answer the question myself.

Suppose $\;r < t\;$ is the least upper bound for
$\;\langle z_n\rangle.$ 
Then $\;f(r) > 0.$ 
Let $\;\epsilon = (1 + r) - r^2 \;\Rightarrow\; \epsilon > 0.$

Since $\;r\;$ is assumed to be the least upper bound, there exists a $\;z_n\;$ that is greater than $\;r - \epsilon.$

Then $\;1 + z_n >  1 + r - \epsilon = r^2 \;\Rightarrow$ 
$\;z_{n+1} > r.\;$ This is a contradiction.

Comment: Even simpler: if $\{z_n\}$ has limit $z$, then $z$ must satisfy
$$
z = \sqrt{1+z}.
$$

Comment: @Math1000 Very nice response.  I was wondering (in general) if this is true.  **How do you know this**?  Does this assertion have a name?  Alternatively, is there an online resource that proves this assertion?  2nd alternative : is it simply a matter of *generalizing* the analysis given in my *answer*?  **Also,** when trying to *generalize*, **must** $z_n$ **be based on a continuous function**?

Comment: I believe you are overthinking this. If $\lim_{n\to\infty}z_n=z$ then clearly $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_{n+1}=z$. So the equality follows simply by taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ of both sides of the recurrence.

Comment: @Again, very nice analysis.  Is the following generalization valid?  If there is a function $\;f(z) \;\ni z_{n+1} = f(z_n),\;$ then $\;z_n\;$ converges $\;\Leftrightarrow \;\exists z_0 \ni f(z_0) = z_0,\;$ and when this happens, $\;z_0\;$ will be the limit of the sequence.

Comment: @Math1000  You can ignore question in previous comment.  As I just discovered, Palka (An Intro to Complex Function Theory) discusses this exact point **a few pages after he posed the problem that I originally queried.**